# Android - Can I Databinding programatically? - without layout XML

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, observable, viewmodel

Below is XML equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve, but without XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_start"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.onClickedStart()}"
    android:text='@{vm.btStartLbl}' />
```

so if I have:

```
ConstraintLayout cl = findViewById(R.id.cl);
Button btn = new Button(MyActivity.this);

btn.setText("How to Data Bind here?");

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){ /* how to databind here? */ });

cl.addView(btn);
```

how to databind it as equivalent as xml above?
is it possible?

Comment: "how to databind it as equivalent as xml above?" --   `btn.setOnClickListener(() -> vm.onClickedStart());`
This assumes that you have a `vm` in scope that has an `onClickedStart()` method. IOW, you do not "databind programmatically", but rather simply program.

Comment: Thanks, let me try - how about: `android:text='@{vm.btStartLbl}'` how to bind it from Java?

Comment: Call `setText(vm.getBtStartLbl())` (modifying that method name to match the actual one, as there are a few possibilities).

Comment: I'm not sure if `vm.getBtStartLbl()` will update my `text` if variable changed, e.g: `vm.label=oldVal;` and `getBtStartLbl(){ return this.label; }` if `vm.label = newVal` will my button text get updated to `newVal`?

Comment: No. You would need to call `setText()` again.

Comment: Thanks, but is it not possible to have it "bind"? reason is because my view is not reference in my ViewModel (VM class)
* your first coment works - thanks *

Comment: "but is it not possible to have it "bind"?" -- somebody, somewhere, has to call `setText()`. With the data binding framework, generated code calls `setText()`. If you are not using the data binding framework, you need to either call `setText()` yourself or find some other library that calls `setText()` for you.

Answer (score 2):

For automatic setting data, you could use `ObservableField`

Simplified version for auto-updating `btn`:

```
ObservableField<String> title = new ObservableField<>();

Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback propertyChangeCallback = new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int property) {
        btn.setText(title.get());
        // here what you want to automatically update
    }
};


public void onStart() {
    // activity/fragment lifecycle method
    title.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(propertyChangeCallback);
}


public void onStop() {
    // activity/fragment lifecycle method
    title.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(propertyChangeCallback);
}
```

And then whenever you call `title.set("some value");`, it will be automatically trigger the update.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try