# How to databind dynamically inflated layouts in MVVM

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have an observable that inflates 3 types of layouts

```
mEventActivityViewModel.getEventPhotos().observe(this, new Observer<List<EventPhotosDao.EventPhotos>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<EventPhotosDao.EventPhotos> eventPhotos) {

        int position = eventPhotos.size();
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                initAddPhotosButton2();
                break;

            case 1:
                inflateOnePhotoLayout();
                break;

            case 2:
                inflateTwoPhotoLayout();
                break;

            default:
                inflateThreePhotoLayout();
                break;


         }
    });
```

How would I databind the dynamically inflated layouts in MVVM architecture? Would all my logic be inside my Activity class?

```
private void inflateOnePhotoLayout() {
        View eventOnePhotosLayout = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.fragevent_photolayout_onephoto, mPhotosLayout, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) eventOnePhotosLayout.findViewById(R.id.fragevent_onephotolayout_image1);
        Glide.with(this).load(mEventPhotos.get(0).getBody()).apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()).into(imageView);
        mPhotosLayout.addView(eventOnePhotosLayout);

        View eventNumPhotos_1 = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.vh_fragevent_numberpictures, mPhotosLayout, false);
        TextView tvNumberPhotos = (TextView) eventNumPhotos_1.findViewById(R.id.vh_fragevent_tv_numberpictures);
        tvNumberPhotos.setText("1");
        mPhotosLayout.addView(eventNumPhotos_1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't have bindings without static XML. You can setup a `LiveData` or an `ObservableField` for each view you want to update.

See [Android - Can I Databinding programatically? - without layout XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386329/android-can-i-databinding-programatically-without-layout-xml)